# Hide quick launch for all pages in root site only

Tags: css, custom-masterpage

I am using the following css to hide the quick launch in SharePoint 2013, but I want it to hide the quick launch only in the root site, NOT in the subsites which inherit the same master page.

```
 #sideNavBox {DISPLAY: none}
 #contentBox {MARGIN-LEFT: 10px}
```

Is there a way to apply this css only to the root site?

Comment: Do the subsites inherit navigation?

Comment: Yes, and they inherit the master page as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend adding a custom action to the web object at the root.
The guys at pattern and practice explains it [well](https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/1852)

Basically create a css file with what you need, put it somewhere and add the custom action

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(rootUrl))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, pwd);

    var web = clientContext.Web; // use this one
    var site = clientContext.Site;

    // Build a custom action to write a link to our new CSS file
    UserCustomAction cssAction = web.UserCustomActions.Add();
    cssAction.Location = "ScriptLink";
    cssAction.Sequence = 100;
    cssAction.ScriptBlock = @"document.write('<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""" + assetLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/contoso.css"" />');";
    cssAction.Name = actionName;

    // Apply
    cssAction.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I would like to apply this css only to the root site and not to the subsites.

Comment: If you use the web object of the root url and not the site object it should only be the root site. Please see the updated codesnippet